# Unrecognised selector sent to instance when trying to insert in CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, runtime-error

I am trying to save some data to **CoreData** but i get the error:

> Restaurant Manager[5971:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ProdusComandat setIdProdus:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x90b8270'

Can someone tell me why?

```
 SessionController* sessionController = [[SessionController alloc]init];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"ComenziActive"];// baza de date
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"numeClient == %@",sessionController.getSessionUsername]];

NSError *err;
NSUInteger count = [self.managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&err];

NSArray *listaElementeBD = [[NSArray alloc]init];


if(count <= 0)
{
    NSEntityDescription *entitydesc;
    entitydesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ComenziActive" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    ComenziActive *comanda = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ComenziActive" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    [comanda setValue:sessionController.getSessionUsername forKey:@"numeClient"];

    ProdusComandat * produsComandat = [[ProdusComandat alloc]init];
    produsComandat.idProdus = [[[(Produs*)produsdb objectID] URIRepresentation] absoluteString];
    produsComandat.cantitateComandata = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.cantitateTextField.text integerValue]];

    [comanda addProduseComandateObject:produsComandat];

}
else
{

    NSError *error;
    listaElementeBD = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    ComenziActive *comanda = [listaElementeBD objectAtIndex: 0];

    NSArray *produse = comanda.produseComandate.allObjects;
    BOOL found =NO;
    for(int i=0;i<[produse count];i++)
    {
        ProdusComandat *p =[[ProdusComandat alloc]init];
        p= produse[i];
        if ([p.idProdus isEqualToString:[[[(Produs*)produsdb objectID] URIRepresentation] absoluteString]]) {
            p.cantitateComandata = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[p.cantitateComandata integerValue] + [self.cantitateTextField.text integerValue]];
            found = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        ProdusComandat * produsComandat = [[ProdusComandat alloc]init];
        produsComandat.idProdus = [[[(Produs*)produsdb objectID] URIRepresentation] absoluteString];
        produsComandat.cantitateComandata = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.cantitateTextField.text integerValue]];

        [comanda addProduseComandateObject:produsComandat];
    }


    NSLog(@"============================");
    NSLog(@"%@", comanda.produseComandate );
}


NSError *error;
[self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

What I am trying to do is get the data from **CoreData** entity **Produs** and copy it's **objectID** to the entity **ProduseComandate** that has this relationship **ComenziActive<----->>ProduseComandate**(relationship one-to-many) if that **objectID** doesn't exist in the table, but if it does exist, I want to add to the value **cantiate** some value that I take from the **TextField**.

Comment: Show the entity and class definition. How is `idProdus` defined?

Comment: Show also the class ProductComandat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to declare it like this:

```
ProdusComandat *produsComandat = [[ProdusComandat alloc]initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```